# How do i use if condition to click on particular button if popup appears in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where popup may appear or may not appear depend on filter options selected. If its appear i do have to click on 'Proceed' button. Please find attached screenshot.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0tN9.png]

**Here is the code**:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="DisplayBCWarningPopUpId" aria-labelledby="ui-id-6" style="position: absolute; height: auto; width: 300px; top: 81px; left: 837px; display: block;" xpath="1">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"></div>
    <div id="DisplayBCWarningPopUpId" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 92px; max-height: none; height: auto;">
        <div id="ApplyFiltersModal">
        <br>
        This will override the following applied filters. Hover over pills to see content changes. Do you wish to proceed?
        <table></table>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="checkbox"></div>
        <div class="btn-delete-custom-dashboard" style="padding-top:15px;">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancelOverrideBC" name="WidgetGenericButtonContainer" buttonenabled="true" class="button-layout WidgetGenericButtonEnabled">
            <script></script>
        <input type="button" value="Proceed" id="btnOkOverrideBC" name="WidgetGenericButtonContainer" buttonenabled="true" class="button-layout WidgetGenericButtonEnabled">
            <script></script>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script></script>
    </div>
```

Once all filters get selected clicking on apply button and then if Popup get displays trying to click on button 'Proceed'.
What i tried is

`if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnOkOverrideBC']")).isDisplayed());  {  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnOkOverrideBC']")).click(); }`

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Once all filters get selected clicking on apply button and then checking with if condition that if 'Proceed' button is displayed click on that button.                                          applyButton.click();
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnOkOverrideBC']")).isDisplayed());
{
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnOkOverrideBC']")).click();
  }

Comment: Can you please [edit] your original post with the additional information, and properly format it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize **`.findElements`** (with *`s`*), this is return a list.

Check the size, `if > 0` it means the element exists.

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnOkOverrideBC']")).size()>0) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnOkOverrideBC']")).click();
}
```